# How can Flash AS3.0 Read file text while text file still writing by C++ program?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

How can Flash AS3.0 Read file text while text file still writing by C++ program ?

I have some code that I asked before + I modify some line but It can read only text file that completely writing.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var toLoad:URLRequest = new URLRequest("example.txt");
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(toLoad);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded, false, 0, true);

function loaded(evt:Event):void
{
    var txtData:String = evt.currentTarget.data;
    txtData = txtData.replace(/^\s+/, '');
    txtData = txtData.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    txtData = txtData.replace(/\s+$/, '')
    var textAr:Array = txtData.split(" ");
 var xArray:Array = new Array;
 var yArray:Array = new Array;
 var i=0;
 var ii = textAr.length;
 while (i < ii)
 { 
  if (textAr[i] != "---")
  {
   xArray.push(textAr[i]);
   yArray.push(textAr[i+1]);
   i+=2;
  }
  else 
  {
   xArray.push("-");
   yArray.push("-");
   i++;
  }
 }
}
```

Now My task is read real time file and send xArray and yArray to another function  but I don't know how can I code it.

please,Help me.

Comment: Not a full depth answer so I just comment: maybe you can read the file every 30 sec or less. So you always get the fresh state of file. You can write program that has the latest data  and new data of the file and add the difference to the function.

Comment: Can you guide me how can I do that ??

Comment: I didn't write answer because I am not AS3 programmer. I know flash can read txt so I tried to give idea how to start. Sorry I can't write a code for it :) Maybe someone read this and help you out in an answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how the C++ program is writing your file, but I suppose it's nothing fancy, it just opens the file, writes the content and closes it. The thing is that the content isn't saved on disk until C++ closes the file (and thus saves it).

So, to solve your problem, you should modify the C++ program (if you can), to write small parts of the content to the file, then close it and open it again. Same thing with your flash program. It won't be realtime, but it would be close enough.

Anyway, a text file isn't the best choice for real time reading. You could use sockets or something else for communication between C++ and Flash.

Comment: I think you could use that too, but you would need a local server running, which goes way beyond a simple C++ program that writes a file.